# Fermat's factorisation in C++

Tags: c++, math, factorization

For fun, I've been implementing some maths stuff in C++, and I've been attempting to implement [Fermats Factorisation Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method), however, I don't know that I understand what it's supposed to return.  This implementation I have, returns `105` for the example number 5959 given in the Wikipedia article.

The pseudocode in Wikipedia looks like this:

> One tries various values of a, hoping that  is a square.

```
FermatFactor(N): // N should be odd
    a → ceil(sqrt(N))
    b2 → a*a - N
    while b2 isn't a square:
        a → a + 1    // equivalently: b2 → b2 + 2*a + 1
        b2 → a*a - N //               a → a + 1
    endwhile
    return a - sqrt(b2) // or a + sqrt(b2)
```

My C++ implementation, look like this:

```
int FermatFactor(int oddNumber)
{
    double a = ceil(sqrt(static_cast<double>(oddNumber)));
    double b2 = a*a - oddNumber;
    std::cout << "B2: " << b2 << "a: " << a << std::endl;

    double tmp = sqrt(b2);
    tmp = round(tmp,1);
    while (compare_doubles(tmp*tmp, b2))  //does this line look correct?
    {
        a = a + 1;
        b2 = a*a - oddNumber;
        std::cout << "B2: " << b2 << "a: " << a << std::endl;
        tmp = sqrt(b2);
        tmp = round(tmp,1);
    }

    return static_cast<int>(a + sqrt(b2));
}

bool compare_doubles(double a, double b)
{
    int diff = std::fabs(a - b);
    return diff < std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
}
```

What is it supposed to return?  It seems to be just returning `a + b`, which is not the factors of `5959`?

**EDIT**

```
double cint(double x){
    double tmp = 0.0;
    if (modf(x,&tmp)>=.5)
        return x>=0?ceil(x):floor(x);
    else
        return x<0?ceil(x):floor(x);
}

double round(double r,unsigned places){
    double off=pow(10,static_cast<double>(places));
    return cint(r*off)/off;
}
```

Comment: `static_cast<double>(b2)`? Is there a reason that's there? Also how is `compare_doubles` defined?

Comment: @jli `b2` was an `int` on my earlier implementation, let me change it, it has no more reason for existance

Comment: I would use integer types for `tmp` and `b2`. In order for the tests to pass, you need an integer square root of `b2` anyway. In fact, an implementation with ints for all local variables return 101. :)

Comment: What's that two-argument round function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do note that you should be doing all those calculations on integer types, not on floating point types. It would be much, much simpler (and possibly more correct).

---

Your `compare_doubles` function is wrong. `diff` should be a `double`.

And once you fix that, you'll need to fix your test line. `compare_doubles` will return true if its inputs are "nearly equal". You need to loop while they are "not nearly equal".

So:

```
bool compare_doubles(double a, double b)
{
    double diff = std::fabs(a - b);
    return diff < std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
}
```

And:

```
while (!compare_doubles(tmp*tmp, b2))  // now it is
{
```

And you will get you the correct result (`101`) for this input.

You'll also need to call your `round` function with `0` as "places" as [vhallac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10474388/635608) points out - you shouldn't be rounding to one digit after the decimal point.

The Wikipedia article you link has the equation that allows you to identify `b` from `N` and `a-b`.

Comment: Heh, I missed the `int diff` bug. :)

Comment: Added reference, made CW for collective effort ;-)

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems in your code:

1. `compare_doubles` return true when they are close enough. So, the while loop condition is inverted.
2. The `round` function requires number of digits after decimal point. So you should use `round(x, 0)`.

As I've suggested, it is easier to use `int` for your datatypes. [Here's](http://ideone.com/EGcsF) working code implemented using integers.

Comment: Damn, missed the round bug :)

Comment: :) Your answer is more comprehensive. Feel free to add that to yours, so that it can be selected as the right one.

Answer (score 2):

The two factors are (a+b) and (a-b).  It is returning one of those.  You can get the other easily.

```
N = (a+b)*(a-b)
a-b = N/(a+b)
```

Comment: How am I supposed to get the other easily from `a + b` ??